# Does initiating a macro from a button in a sheet change how vba interprates the code?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works fine when I run it from the vba editor. When I assign this macro to a button, however, it does not copy the columns as written.  The other parts of the code work?

Is there something about assigning the macro that changes how the code is interpreted?

```
Sub copy_ids_user_output()

'   copy the first column to the last column
    Dim last_col As Integer
    last_col = Worksheets("usersFullOutput.csv").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    Debug.Print last_col

    Columns(1).Copy Columns(last_col + 1)

    Worksheets("WorkStation").Range("B9").Value = Now()
    MsgBox "id's copied to last col in email logs sheet"
End Sub¨
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me both ways.  When you run it are there any error msgs?  Does it just go through without any issues other than the column didn't paste over?

Comment: It shows no errors, it puts the `Now()` in the right spot and shows the `MsgBox`.  No idea whats going on here.  I'm on a mac.  Does that matter?

Comment: Not sure about the mac.  This is a long shot but has happened to me, is the font color set to white or no color?  Sounds crazy I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood well, you have:

1. a clickable button placed in `Worksheets("WorkStation")`;
2. a column in `Worksheets("usersFullOutput.csv")` that you want to be copied at the end of the same sheet

If this is the case, most probably you have this behavior because you don't reference the worksheet in the line of code that executes the copy:

```
Columns(1).Copy Columns(last_col + 1)
```

Which means:

- When you run from VBA editor, you're watching the sheet `usersFullOutput.csv` so the above line of code executes on this sheet;
- When you run from the button, you're watching the sheet `WorkStation` and since you don't reference any sheet in the above line, it assumes to execute on this other sheet.

If this is the problem, just add the worksheet reference:

```
Worksheets("usersFullOutput.csv").Columns(1).Copy Worksheets("usersFullOutput.csv").Columns(last_col + 1)
```

If this is not the problem, please clarify on which worksheets you work on and I will delete/adapt my answer accordingly.

P.s. for information, anyway, the answer to your title question "Does initiating a macro from a button in a sheet change how vba interprates the code?" is *no, it doesn't; but adding no references to the variables change  the way VBA interprets them because it chooses the default ones, which are not always the same you want*.

Comment: Nailed it.  Nice catch!!

Comment: try using `With worksheetname` and then always user `.columns` etc